# Finding the newest file in folder

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the newest file a particular folder.

```
Sub FindFile()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim MyDateTime As Date
Dim MyDate As Date

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

MyFolder = "C:\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.pdf")

NextRow = 1
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    MyDateTime = FileDateTime(MyFolder & MyFile)
    sh1.Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = MyFolder & MyFile
    sh1.Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = MyDateTime
    MyDate = Int(MyDateTime)
    If MyDate = Date Then
        sh1.Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = "Y"
    End If
    NextRow = NextRow + 1
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

This lists all the files in the spreadsheet.  Without using Sort, is there a better way I can just grab the newest filename and assign it to a variable?

*Ideally I'd like to find the file without even have to list them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the name of the filename of the newest file, compare the previous date and the new date and store the higher date into one variable and the filename of the current file in the loop into another variable.

Eventually, one date will be stored that is higher than all the others and this nets you the file you want. In code, it can be done like so:

```
Sub FindFileMod()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim MyDateTime As Date
Dim MyDate As Date
Dim MaxDateTime As Date
Dim MyFileName As String

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

MyFolder = "C:\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.pdf")
MaxDateTime = 0

NextRow = 1
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    MyDateTime = FileDateTime(MyFolder & MyFile)
    If MyDateTime > MaxDateTime Then
        MaxDateTime = MyDateTime
        MyFileName = MyFolder & MyFile
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Debug.Print MyFileName
Debug.Print MaxDateTime

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps. :)